# Second Schengen visa application refused within two days

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

I had applied for a Schengen visa for Paris on June 13 and my visa was refused on June 25 stating that “justification provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable”. And again I reapplied the same on nov 18 and once again my visa has been denied at the next day nov 19 itself stating the same above reason “justification provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable”. My travel date was dec 6 to 12.

Kindly advise is it normal that the reconsideration visa will get refused within 2 days form submission date…

Comment: You know, the visa officials are not idiots. If you submit the same application twice, they will notice.

Comment: `justification provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable` Why don't you provide proper evidence to justify your case rather than applying repeatedly, just to get rejected ?

Answer (score 10):

"...is it normal that the reconsideration visa will get cancelled within 2 days from submission date..."

In the Schengen regime, they don't have a 'reconsideration visa'.  So your application would have been treated as a `fresh application` within your history of applications.

If your previous application was unsuccessful, they would focus on the corrective measures you have taken to see if you now qualify. Based upon what you wrote, you made it real easy for them and they were able to give a proportionate turn-around time for their decision.  Plus they would have chalked up the turn-around time in their performance stats.

The "*justification provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable*" is a grave refusal ground and normally needs a lot of work from the applicant to overcome.  If you spend more time on correcting it, they will consider the application more carefully and give a more acceptable turn-around time.

Comment: I read this when you first posted it and it never occurred to me... two day turn around is beyond acceptable into awesome... unfortunately for the OP it meant disapproval, but still, if only all applicants were handled that expeditiously, for positives as well.

Comment: @CGCampbell, paradoxically, the consulate owes him a thank you for helping to improve their stats.